# Unity - IBM watson and SendBird SDK, websocket-sharp conflicts with each other they both have the same Namespace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, sendbird, websocket-sharp

Development Environment:

- Unity 2018.3.5f1
- IBM Waston SDK: unity-sdk-3.4.1, unity-sdk-core-0.3.0
- SendBird .NET SDK
- Windows 7

Problem :
Both have the same name for websocket-sharp which causing conflicts with code, unable to use both in one project.

> Error : PrecompiledAssemblyException: Multiple precompiled assemblies
>   with the same name websocket-sharp.dll included for the current
>   platform. Only one assembly with the same name is allowed per
>   platform.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can delete the websocket-sharp library from the Unity SDK Core.

```
Plugins/websocket-sharp.dll
```

We will need to create a new dll with an ibm-specific namespace.